# Question about arrays and buttons in eclipse + android java project

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

well im kind of new to eclipse anyways i was wondering is there a way for me to create an array of buttons in the java code rather then a xml file, then define there positions on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Every Button object is a view itself. Therefore, it can be added to a parent Layout (like the LinearLayout). The easiest way IMHO is creating the XML only for the things you know that will not change, or maybe using a TableLayout. Then, add the buttons.

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
Button[] btnArray = new Button[3];
for(Button button : btnArray){
    button = new Button(/*Required params */);
    // button.something , play with text and onclick and positions...
    mainLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: yeah but could u explain the params code a bit when i tried to do it, it was my params code that i messed up on the most

Comment: You should paste your code so we can identify where is the mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i);
    final int id_ = btn.getId();
    btn.setText("button " + id_);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
    linear.addView(btn, params);

    btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                    "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```